# OAuth 2.0 on consolibyte SDK (quickbooks)

Tags: php, oauth, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

Good Day, I am creating an app that uses QuickBooks API, its working fine now. but when I tried to connect another QuickBooks company as I made new developer account, I can't see the keys like QUICKBOOK_TOKEN and QBO_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY which was required by the plugin to connect.. then I realized this was what QuickBooks is referring to with their notification about OAuth 2.0.

now my question is it possible to implement OAuth 2.0 using the SDK from https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php , also is it possible to implement them both ( OAuth 1.0a + OAuth 2.0 ), if so can you please tell me where to start or if not how can I maybe migrate from OAuth 1.0 to OAuth 2.0 ...

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: any comments is much appreciated thanks :)